# DIN rail terminal block resistor

Tags: plc, 4-20ma, industrial, terminal-block, signal-conversion

Is there a reliable solution for placing my own **through hole resistor into a DIN rail mountable terminal block**? Or is there any off the shelf solution the use a resistor to **convert my 4-20mA current output** of my pressure sensor **to 2-10V signal**?

I'm using a LOGO! smart relay (PLC) which only has analog voltage input and I want the solution to be **cheaper than buying an analog expansion module**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Weidmüller has such DIN terminal blocks with built-in components.](https://www.weidmueller.com/int/products/connectivity/terminal_blocks/terminal_blocks_with_electronic_components.jsp)

They have some often used components as diodes or indicator LEDs in stock. For resistors they have terminal blocks with internal soldering lugs so you can solder the needed resistor in yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Through-hole components are pretty easy to connect to standard DIN-rail mounted terminal blocks. Either screw or spring-clamp terminals would be fine.  You can use 3- or 4-terminal blocks to have enough terminals to give each lead of your resistor its own terminal, and still have connections for a couple of wires at each point.  If you want to make it touch-safe, you can add heat-shrink tubing to the exposed resistor leads.

Answer (score 1):

To convert a 4-20mA current output to a 2-10V signal, you can use an external resistor. Ohm's Law (V = I * R) can help determine the resistor value needed. For example, a 250-ohm resistor could convert a 4-20mA current to a 1-5V signal.

Ensure the resistor can handle the power dissipation (P = I^2 * R) and select one with appropriate tolerance. You might need to experiment and adjust the resistor value based on your specific sensor and system requirements.

Remember to verify the voltage drop across the resistor and ensure it falls within your PLC's input voltage range.

As for DIN rail mounting, you may need to get creative with mounting brackets or consider ready-made solutions that offer this functionality. Always follow safety guidelines and ensure proper insulation and protection for your setup.

Comment: Alex - Hi, Our systems indicate that this post was mostly or completely copied from elsewhere, but there is no [reference](/help/referencing). Also note that we do not want LLM-generated (e.g. ChatGPT) answers (those are impossible to correctly reference, since the original sources of training data are unknown - so using them is always classed as plagiarism here). Please explain the original source of this answer. TY